# Combinations of a group into multiple groups without repetition

Tags: java, kotlin, unique, combinations

We have a list of elements **[A,B,C,D,E]** and **3 groups** to combine those elements, I would like to print a list of all **unique combinations without repetition for those 3 groups**. Only groups of lengths [2,2,1] are valid (it could be filtered after, it's not a must, but it would be nice efficiently wise, and, if needed, the lengths of the groups could be specified manually as a parameter). What I mean for unique without repetition:

[[A,B],[C,D],[E]] and [[C,D],[A,B],[E]] and [[B,A],[C,D],[E]] would be the same, so It doesn't matter the order of the elements inside of a group or the order of groups, I'm not interested in those combinations.

In my particular case I have 16 items and 3 groups of 5, 5, and 6 items each group.

An example of what I want to achieve:

```
/**
 * Returns all the unique combinations of a group into multiple groups
 * [data] the group of elements to combine
 * [numberOfGroups] the number of groups
 */
fun combinations(data: List<String>, numberOfGroups: Int): List<List<List<String>>> {
    // The combinations code
}

val data = listOf("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
print(combinations(data, 3))
```

The output will be something like this:

```
[
   [[A,B],[C,D],[E]],
   [[A,D],[B,C],[E]],
   ...
]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Nikolas First I tried to came with the solution by myself, and either is too complex or I'm not smart enough (also I don't have the mathematical background). I found out about the n! / (r!(n−r)!) combination's formula, but I think It doesn't apply here, and I tried Sets.powerSet(Sets.newHashSet(myItemsList)) from Guava's library. I also spend several hours looking for examples, but none of them applied.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the answer to your problem in general, but I'll try to solve this particular case of splitting a list of 5 elements into the groups [2, 2, 1] and share some principles that could help you to devise a more general solution.

First, let's talk about how to represent the result. If the order of elements inside a group is not significant, it's convenient to represent a group with a `Set<String>`, so that `setOf("A", "B")` equals `setOf("B", "A")`. Then if the order of the groups themselves in a combination doesn't matter, that combination can be a set of groups, i.e. `Set<Set<String>>`.

Now about the algorithm itself. It's convenient to structure such algorithm as a recursive search: you select the first group of items from your data and then solve the problem for the data without the selected items, and combine the first group with all solutions except it. So our the function that searches for combinations can be like the following:

```
fun combinationSequence(data: List<String>): Sequence<Set<Set<String>>> = sequence {
    for (group in possibleFirstGroups(data)) {
        val remaining = data - group
        if (remaining.isEmpty()) {
            yield(setOf(group))
        } else {
            yieldAll(combinationSequence(remaining).map { r -> setOf(group) + r })
        }
    }
}
```

Then how to select the first group in all possible ways. For the groups of size 1 or 2 we can select the first element of group from all elements of data and then select the second element from the remaining ones:

```
fun possibleFirstGroups(data: List<String>): Sequence<Set<String>> =
        when (data.size) {
            0 -> emptySequence()
            1, 2 -> sequenceOf(data.toSet())
            else -> sequence {
                for (e1 in data) {
                    for (e2 in data - e1) {
                        yield(setOf(e1, e2))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Our `combinationSequence` return results, but there will be a lot of duplicates, like `[[A, B], [C, D], [E]]` and `[[C, D], [A, B], [E]]`. To leave only distinct of them we can use the function `distinct`:

```
combinationSequence(data).distinct().forEach { println(it) }
```

Note that the complexity of this solution raises exponentially with the number of items, so I don't expect the solution for 16 elements to terminate in a timely manner :)

One approach to reduce the complexity is pruning the search space. For example, if we've already found *all* combinations starting with `[A, B]` group, we can avoid yielding combinations that contain that group somewhere in the middle, like `[C, D], [A, B], ...`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution in Python inspired by [All Grouping Permutations Built-in Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72342083/all-grouping-permutations-built-in-functions). I'll leave it as an exercise to write it in your preferred language.

```py
from itertools import combinations, product, starmap
from operator import add
from collections import Counter

def pair_splittings(elements, k):
    elements = frozenset(elements)
    for A in combinations(elements, k):
        B = tuple(elements - frozenset(A))
        yield (A, B)

def set_pair_splittings(elements, k):
    # deduplicate: always put the first element in the first group.
    n0, *rest = elements
    for A, B in pair_splittings(rest, k - 1):
        yield ((n0,) + A, B)

# set to 1 to reduce memory consumption but also slow things down.
EXTRA_LAZY = 0

def even_splittings(elements, num_bins):
    # special case when all bins are the same size.

    assert len(elements) % num_bins == 0
    bin_size = len(elements) // num_bins

    if num_bins == 1:
        yield (tuple(elements),)
        return

    k = num_bins // 2
    for half1, half2 in set_pair_splittings(elements, k*bin_size):
        
        if not EXTRA_LAZY:
            # Option 1: a little bit eager. ##########################
            # Here, product() stores both sequences that it's
            # iterating through. This is much faster than re-computing
            # half2_splittings over and over. Note that storing both
            # halves is much cheaper than storing their entire product,
            # so this is still somewhat lazy.

            half1_splittings = even_splittings(half1, k)
            half2_splittings = even_splittings(half2, num_bins-k)
            half_choices = product(half1_splittings, half2_splittings)
            yield from starmap(add, half_choices)

        else:
            # Option 2: extra-lazy. ##################################
            # If you're dealing with bigger numbers and minimal memory,
            # this might be a better aproach.

            for choices1 in even_splittings(half1, k):
                for choices2 in even_splittings(half2, num_bins-k):
                    yield choices1 + choices2


def splittings_helper(elements, bin_counts):
    assert sum(size * count for size, count in bin_counts) == len(elements)

    if len(bin_counts) == 1:
        [(size, count)] = bin_counts
        yield from even_splittings(elements, count)
        return

    k = len(bin_counts)//2
    left, right = bin_counts[:k], bin_counts[k:]
    left_size = sum(size*count for size, count in left)

    for half1, half2 in pair_splittings(elements, left_size):
        if not EXTRA_LAZY:
            half1_splittings = splittings_helper(half1, bin_counts=left)
            half2_splittings = splittings_helper(half2, bin_counts=right)
            half_choices = product(half1_splittings, half2_splittings)
            yield from starmap(add, half_choices)
        else:
            for choices1 in splittings_helper(half1, bin_counts=left):
                for choices2 in splittings_helper(half2, bin_counts=right):
                    yield choices1 + choices2

def splittings(elements, bins):
    return splittings_helper(elements, tuple(Counter(bins).items()))
```

Example usage:

```py
for x in splittings("ABCDE", bins=(2,2,1)):
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
(('E', 'B'), ('D', 'A'), ('C',))
(('E', 'D'), ('B', 'A'), ('C',))
(('E', 'A'), ('B', 'D'), ('C',))
(('E', 'C'), ('D', 'A'), ('B',))
(('E', 'D'), ('C', 'A'), ('B',))
(('E', 'A'), ('C', 'D'), ('B',))
(('E', 'B'), ('C', 'A'), ('D',))
(('E', 'C'), ('B', 'A'), ('D',))
(('E', 'A'), ('B', 'C'), ('D',))
(('E', 'B'), ('C', 'D'), ('A',))
(('E', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('A',))
(('E', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('A',))
(('A', 'B'), ('C', 'D'), ('E',))
(('A', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('E',))
(('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('E',))
```

Comment: This is extremely helpful! I wonder if we can generalize this solution in following two ways. 
1.Allowing the case that putting 7 elements to bin=(2,1,2), which is equivalent to first choose 5 from 7, then put into bin=(2,1,2). 
2.Allowing the option to treat (('A','B'),('C',D'),('E')) different from (('C','D'),('A',B'),('E')). 
Thank you!

Comment: @Aliceyuenyuen Sure, you could do everything with recursive applications of `pair_splittings`, never using `set_pair_splittings()`. You also wouldn't need the `even_splittings` function at all. But that is solving a different problem, so I'm not going to edit this answer.